# broken vertices after export

Tags: vertices

when I export my model to the game, the vertices are broken, causing problems in the texture
if anyone has any idea why this is happening i would appreciate the help and how to fix it, thanks
(in the first image it is before exporting it, everything is ''fine'')
[image]

after making some modifications in the normals and doing the Merge by Distance some parts are unified, others are not, but I still have a "shading" problem for the broken vertices

[image]
[image]

when I put recalculate normals, it is as if it were inverted, if a part is dark, when recalculating that part it becomes lighter but the one that was lighter becomes darker
[image]

[image]

Here the file to see [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

SOLVED: I recalculated the polygons of the conflicting part in Zbrush and re-imported it to blender, the smooth tone was better, I also placed a proper normal map.

Comment: Check the face orientation of your model. You can turn the orientation display on on the Viewport Overlay menu by checking Face Orientation. Your whole model should be blue. If any of it is red, go into Edit mode, select All, and Shift-N to recalculate the Normals. If that doesn't fix it, share your Blend file via  https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Hello, it didn't work, there I assigned the .blend file

Comment: Can't see any obvious problems causing the problem but I'm no expert. Maybe someone else can help now that you've added the file. Incidentally, which format did you use to export/import the file? (fbx, gltf, obj, etc.?)

Comment: import obj and after export .xml (codewalker XML plugin that is used to export and import to games like GTA V) 
I have already consulted, the problem does not seem to be with the plugin, but with the mesh itself, since when giving the shade auto smooth it gives a shading on the right side, and when exporting it it is cut in the middle
If I hit recalculate normals, you can see in the last photo I added how they are inverted, I need both sides to be the same
note: I made the model in ZBRUSH using mirror to copy parts, made zremesher to lower the polygons and then imported it into blender

Comment: Ok. I know nothing about external programs and third-party addons so can't comment further. The only thing I did notice was that you had custom split normals on the object, but clearing them made no difference so I didn't consider it worth mentioning them.

Comment: I fixed it and updated the post.
Thank you for your interest in wanting to help me!

Comment: Good! You should really add that as an answer rather than just updating the question.